# how to convert encrypt method to decrypt

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I have the following method that I want to decrypt.  The following method Encrypts. What should I do to decrypt?

**Code**

```
PlainString = "5lg3yg7Q+Y8="

func tripleDesEncrypt(PlainString: String) -> String {

    let keyData         = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD"
    let PlainStringvar  = PlainString

    guard let data = PlainStringvar.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return ""           
    }

    let cryptData   = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.count) + kCCBlockSize3DES)!

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                              algoritm,
                              options,
                              keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                              nil,
                              data.bytes, data.count,
                              cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

       var base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)


        return base64cryptString //// encodeString(str: base64cryptString)

    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never did encrypt/decrypt on Swift but based on that code you just need to change this line

```
let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
```

to

```
let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
```

While making a small search for this answer I came across this 
https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/CommonCrypto-in-Swift

It might be useful, not only as a library that you can use, but to study code and also looks that you're new to the Swift language so I advise you to take a look

Comment: There is a little more to it depending on the implementation. One thing is if padding is used, the usual option, the output buffer must be sized larger than the data in order to contain the extra padding bytes. The linked implementation does handle that and on cursory examination seems a good implementation.

Comment: As I said, I never implemented Encryption/Decryption thus pointing to a Library containing the some content

Answer (score 1):

Your `tripleDesEncrypt` does not compile in Swift 4, so I needed to fix it:

```
func tripleDesEncrypt(plainString: String) -> String {

    let keyData         = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD".data(using: .utf8)!

    //Converting plainString to UTF-8 encoded data
    guard let data = plainString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return ""
    }

    var cryptData   = Data(count: data.count + kCCBlockSize3DES)

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
    let operation: CCOperation = CCOperation(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = CCOptions(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    //Encrypting UTF-8 encoded data in 3DES, ECB, PKCS7 with keyData
    let cryptStatus = keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {mutableBytes in
                CCCrypt(operation,
                        algoritm,
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        nil,
                        dataBytes, data.count,
                        mutableBytes, cryptData.count,
                        &numBytesEncrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) {
        //Converting encrypted data into base-64 String
        cryptData.count = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
        let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        return base64cryptString
    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        return ""
    }
}
```

The code is made of 3 parts:

- Converting plainString to UTF-8 encoded data
- Encrypting UTF-8 encoded data in 3DES, ECB, PKCS7 with keyData
- Converting encrypted data into base-64 String

So, to decrypt, you need to apply inverse conversion in reversed order:

- Converting base-64 String into encrypted data
- Decrypting to UTF-8 encoded data in 3DES, ECB, PKCS7 with keyData
- Converting UTF-8 encoded data into plainString

The method looks like this:

```
func tripleDesDecrypt(base64String: String) -> String {

    let keyData         = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD".data(using: .utf8)!

    //Converting base-64 String into encrypted data
    guard let encryptedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
        return ""
    }

    var decryptedData   = Data(count: encryptedData.count)

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
    let operation: CCOperation = CCOperation(kCCDecrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = CCOptions(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesDecrypted :size_t = 0

    //Decrypting to UTF-8 encoded data in 3DES, ECB, PKCS7 with keyData
    let cryptStatus = keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
        encryptedData.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            decryptedData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {mutableBytes in
                CCCrypt(operation,
                        algoritm,
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        nil,
                        dataBytes, encryptedData.count,
                        mutableBytes, decryptedData.count,
                        &numBytesDecrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) {
        //Converting UTF-8 encoded data into plainString
        let plainString = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        return plainString
    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        return ""
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let encryptedString = tripleDesEncrypt(plainString: "This is a test.")
print(encryptedString) //->QmWafUwPY/MVWu3lHa3c5A==

let decryptedString = tripleDesDecrypt(base64String: encryptedString)
print(decryptedString) //->This is a test.

//Try by yourself...
let origString = tripleDesDecrypt(base64String: "5lg3yg7Q+Y8=")
print(origString)
```